# Unable to solve a differential equation using sympy analytically

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I was doing a problem and came across two differential equation. When I try to solve the equation using sympy , I was only able to solve one of them. Can someone tell me if it's possible.
This is the code,
[Code here I tried to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ebz6.png)

Comment: Please actually ask your question here rather than just leaving a link to something else.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry @OscarBenjamin i uploaded the screenshot of the code from jupyter notebook. But it forms like a link

Comment: Just type your actual question, equation and code in here. Screenshots are annoying in any case because no one wants to have to manually type out the code from them.

Comment: The immediate error says that `dsolve(eqn, T(t))` has the wrong second argument. Try with leaving it out or using only `T`. You might still get that the equation is not solvable by sympy.